# Zend Framework 2 SOAP Fault Exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to know what is the original exception details in my SOAP code, I have a SOAP server that handles requests as the following:

```
$options = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'actor' => someUriAString,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'uri' => someUriAString);
$server = new Server(null, $options);
$server->setClass('SomeClass');
$server->setReturnResponse(true);
$serverResponse = $server->handle();
```

and then I check if an exception occurs as the following:

```
if ($serverResponse instanceof \SoapFault) {
    //log the $serverResponse exception details
}
```

but when I log this exception I got something like this:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'SoapFault exception: [Receiver] Unknown error
```

the thing I need to know is the original exception details... like SQL exception, or for example ORMException,...etc. i.e. I need the exact original exception details...

I already tried to `registerFaultException` as following example:

```
$server->registerFaultException('Doctrine\ORM\ORMException');
```

I don't know if this is right, but the problem is that there may occur other types of exception, I can not register them since I don't know what exception could occur in my code!

Comment: I had the same problem, and finally ended up by catching all exceptions (yes, `Exception` class) and throw, manually, a `SoapFault` exception. Everything is catched and correctly handled by SoapServer, with no use of `registerFaultException` method. You can play with `instanceof` or `getclass` to set the faultcode to whatever you want, and then handle exceptions client-side playing with this faultcode.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the expections are setup, but you can get Previous exception message:

```
$message->getPrevious();
```

You can iterate overthem like this:

```
if($message instanceof \Exception) {
    do {
       echo sprintf(
            "%s:%d %s (%d) [%s]\n", 
            $message->getFile(), 
            $message->getLine(), 
            $message->getMessage(), 
            $message->getCode(), 
            get_class($message)
       );
    }
    while($message = $message->getPrevious());
}
```

Comment: This did not work... and I don't think this should work, because the way the SoapFault exception is raised is by "return"ing new SoapFault exception with the message 'Unknown error' since the original exception is not registered using `registerFaultException`